# Graphite console.log of writer is being spammed with unix timestamp

Tags: linux, centos, graphite

My console.log grows to 5 GB throughout the day. This is exaple of console.log

```
22/07/2017 00:00:02 :: 1500049680
22/07/2017 00:00:02 :: 1500049680
22/07/2017 00:00:02 :: 1500049680
22/07/2017 00:00:02 :: 1500052620
22/07/2017 00:00:02 :: 1499967240
22/07/2017 00:00:02 :: 1499967240
22/07/2017 00:00:02 :: 1500049680
```

On the another server with Gentoo same configs in /opt/graphite/conf/carbon-daemons/writer-1/. And there is no spamming. 
Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: What version of graphite?

Comment: version  is 0.10.0

Comment: I'm not clear 0.10.0 was ever released (see the list of version in the menu at http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releases/1_0_2.html, and the tags in the git repo).  All the documentation at graphite.readthedocs.io has "Graphite 0.10.0" in the title, which is rather unhelpful.  Can you be more specific about which version you're actually running (package name/version, or where you got the source from etc)